# Breeze.js and odata: anything like inlineCount but without filtering?

Tags: odata, breeze, hottowel

In Breeze.js inlineCount(http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityQuery.html#method_inlineCount) implements the odata inlinecount parameter (http://www.odata.org/documentation/uri-conventions#InlinecountSystemQueryOption)

so it shows the total count after filtering but without paging.

But is there an "inline" way in either Breeze or odata to also get the full count without filtering in a single breeze query?  i.e. the count of all records that would have been returned without the specified filtering.  I know I could do a seperate query for this, but was hoping for a way to do it in a single operation.

Apologies if this is a silly question; I'm still getting up to speed with odata and Breeze. The reason I ask is I'm using datatables.net and it expects both the total count, filtered count and number of records so it can display something like

```
Showing 1 to 10 of 48 entries (filtered from 148 total entries)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot come up with an easy way to do this with a single query.

If I understand your question, you want basically three counts for each query you submit

1. The count of the query results actually returned - ( easily
   obtained via 'results.length' )
2. The count of the query results    that would have been returned
   without any skip or take ( obtained via    the ".inlinecount()"
   method on the query.
3. The count of the query    results that would have been returned
   without any filter or skip or    take. i.e. the count of the entire
   "resource".  ( This one is difficult without a separate query).

If this is correct, then I think that you are stuck with performing two queries, one to get the count for the entire "resource" (i.e. #3 above) and another using the "inlinecount" method for #1 and #2

Comment: Thanks Jay, yes you've understood my question perfectly and it's (3) that I was looking for. I sort of suspected that was the case :)  +1 and I'll mark as the answer if noone else has any bright ideas?  Any hooks on breeze server side where I could add something like this?